# What skills, programs, etc. are needed to create an OS from scratch?

Tags: operating-system

The title explains it.  What computer skills, programs, et cetera are needed to make an operating system?  I know I am a long way away in terms of skills to do this but I want to know what I should be aiming to learn to accomplish this goal of mine.

Comment: Very deep knowledge of assembly programming, deep knowledge of OS principles, very detailed knowledge of processor architecture, etc, etc, etc. It isn't easy. Try cloning DOS first, and then see what you think. You'll need some kind of VM for testing, and a very thorough knowledge of C for the (more) high level parts. It's not easy, and most programmers can't even get close. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a BS in Computer Science. Then maybe go for a Master's degree.  Go heavy on the math.

Generally you need a low level language that you can compile to binary.  A shop near me, Green Hills Software makes compilers and is located next to an excellent school.  You could look into interning with them.

There are some great books in your area of study too.

You can buy simple chips online and write code for them.  I know someone who built little robots in his garage from parts online.  He would design super simple motherboards and have them built in China, write the code, and solder wheels, wings, and sensors on.  He sold one of his models to NASA.

I hope you do it!